# Elasticsearch _update_by_query updates docs anyway even in case of versions conflicts

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST and trying to make _update_by_query operation
(ES v. 6.5.1, NEST v.6.4.0)

```
var response = await client.UpdateByQueryAsync<T> (x => {
    x.Query ( * query text * )
    .Index (index)
    .Script ( * script * )
}, cancellationToken);
```

If I have for example two updates one by one under the same documents I will get list of failures caused by different versions (in case I add `conflicts.Proceed`) or exception will be thrown (by default or in case `conflicts.Abort`)

But in both cases documents being updated.

[Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) says update will happen only when versions are the same. Maybe someone faced this issue and can explain why docs are updated anyway?